# OpenCTI searchAndScreenPop method

Tags: lightning, javascript, opencti

How can I use the searchAndScreenPop method (Lightning) to search by a custom field?
For example :

I'm trying to use this method to popup a Lead which has the phone number as a param, but I don't want it to search for the default Phone field - I want it to search in other fields like mobilePhone or other custom field.

How can I achieve it?

I tried :

```
var callback22 = function(response) {
        if (response.success) {
        console.log('API method call executed successfully! returnValue:',
        response.returnValue);

        } else {
        console.error('Something went wrong! Errors:', response.errors);
        }
        };
        function searchAndScreenPop() {
        sforce.opencti.searchAndScreenPop({ searchParams : '05067898766' ,defaultFieldValues:{MobilePhone: '05067898766'},callType : sforce.opencti.CALL_TYPE.INBOUND, deferred: false,
        callback : callback22 });
        }
```

Many Thanks!